# How to selectively filter based on a dimension?

Tags: tableau-api

[Link to tableau graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGnZT.png)

I want to selectively filter the above graph based on the year. For example, when I deselect December, I want only the 2018 values to be excluded while keeping the December values for the other years.

Tableau version: 2018.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated field called something like "year-month of order date" that contains logic such as `YEAR(Order Date) * 100 + MONTH(Order Date)`. Drag that field to the filter box and include it on the dashboard. Then the user can exclude any combination of year and month combination.